# Graph for tire contact patch, related to negative camber in a car tire

Tags: graphing-functions

I don't know if this should be on stack overflow or here, but I'm gonna ask it anyway:

I need an equation for the graph of relation between the camber angle (the angle between the ground and the axis of rotation) and contact patch in a tire.

For angle $\theta=0$, the area is a.
For some angle $\theta_{max}>\theta$, the area is $a_{max}>a$.
For another angle $\theta_{min}>\theta_{max}$, the area theoretically is 0. (This is practically impossible.)

X axis is camber angle, while y axis is contact patch.
The graph is a curve with $\theta_{max}$ in the first quadrant.
The curve also doesn't start from 0, but from $a$ (area) on y axis, moving up until $a_{max}$, corresponding to $\theta_{max}$ on x axis and then falling until it intersects the x axis at $\theta_{min}$.

Any quick and dirty solution would do, as long as it bears some semblance to the curve I described above. Thanks in advance. Also, I couldn't post the picture of the graph because either the internet is crap, or there's​ something wrong with my mobile phone, so I'm sorry.

Comment: Also apparently, MathJax isn't working. I don't know how it appears on your (the viewer's) computer or phone, but it doesn't seem to work here. I'm 15 years old, so I might not be using it correctly.

Comment: MathJax only works if you surround it with dollar signs ($). I submitted an edit to correct this.

Comment: @glorfindel Thanks.

Comment: At a basic level, camber angle doesn’t have much do to with the *area* of the contact patch. That’s dominated by the load on the tire. What it does affect greatly is the *shape* of the contact patch. Going beyond this, tire construction will affect the area with changing camber, but you’re not going to be able to model that without more information. If you’re trying to match an existing curve, that’s a different matter.

Comment: But the suspension under load doesn't just move up or down. The tire also rotates along the car's forward axis under load. That changes the camber which changes the area of the patch.

Comment: Area does change with camber, as the inner side walls of the tire deform and become flat in line with the tread (as the Tyre is a soft body) at a specific negative camber angle. Anything beyond that, the area decreases.

Comment: I wish I would have been able to post a picture